# Data Mining/Statistical Methods to find trends, peaks, etc

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, data-mining

currently I am working on a project for my final exam. The data is coming from a streaming plattform. The data I am using are some logging data (data when customers have problems with the streaming service).
My knowledge in this topic is not the best but I will try to explain my current progress and what my task is. In the first steps I made some data preparation. After this step I have following data structure:

- **eventTime** - time when error occured
- **deviceId** - device identifier
- **errorCode** - specific code, which can be used to get more information of the error

So these are the only attributes I have. All other attributes, which are not listed, were irrelevant. In the first step I created time ranges (15 minutes). For each time period I counted the errors. Now I want to make some time series analysis. I need some algorithms/strategies to detect:

- trends
- jumps (e.g. count was static 5, but suddenly jumped to 10 and it stays at 10)
- peaks/anomalies (static 5, suddenly 15 for on range, then back to 5

I found a moving average method. But with this the data is slightly manipulated and it is only suitable to see if there are trends. Do you have some suggestions which methods I could use for each of the points? One more problem is that I need to do a analysis for every error type (there are about 20000). Looking at each graph would take too much time. For example: I want the top 30 errors which have an upgoing trend. Is there a solution for this? It would be helpful if a algorithm just tells me wether the error makes problems or not.

It would be nice if someone could help me with my problem. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm you needs is change point detection.
It's a ton of ideas.
In python, [ruptures](http://ctruong.perso.math.cnrs.fr/ruptures-docs/build/html/index.html) is a package, it's really nice to understand cp detection.
Basic idea is separated 3 component.

**1.How to define searching area.**
(all data at same time, window..)

**2.How to compare the data.**
(model, statistic.....)

**3.How to restrict cp.**
(by increasing cp, model is easy to fit)

This theory can be programmed manually easily, so try to understand algorithm and try it.